# Amazon S3 object redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-redirect

Is it possible to put a redirect header on a s3-object? Like a 301 redirect.

For example:

```
mybucket.amazon-aws.com/myobject --> example.com/test
```

Preferably by setting a header like this on the object:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/test
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Within the last month, this functionality has just been added.

You can find the API documentation here:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html

When you PUT your object, you need to set the `x-amz-website-redirect-location` key against that object to the 301 redirect that you wish to use.

You can also use the console.

[image]

Comment: Does this work for arbitrary objects? Or only for their special HTML-static-site stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no support for wildcards, so I can't make a redirect to remove the trailing `/index.html` on my static site.

Comment: Will this work if using cloudfront with s3? Cloudfront is routing to my site, but then downloading the file instead of following the redirect rule i've defined in s3.

Comment: @Learner AFAIK no, It needs to be accessed through the s3 website endpoint. In fact cloudfront will likely strip the custom s3 header.

Answer (score 15):

In case if website hosting is enabled for the bucket, there is an alternative way to add 301 redirect.
According to it redirection rules are described on the bucket level in XML-format, and  can be specified in bucket's properties via AWS S3 Console (Static Website Hosting section).
Full documentation about its syntax currently can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax).

This approach is convenient when you have massive URL movements as far as it's easier to manage all redirections in one place. For instance it's possible to define redirection rules

```
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>index.php</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <ReplaceKeyWith>index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>blog.php?id=21</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <ReplaceKeyWith>mysql-utf-8-database-creation-snippet.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

It looks like it's the same as creating fake objects and specifying x-amz-website-redirect-location metadata for them.
The bad news are that there are could be not more than 50 such rules in XML for one bucket.
And yes, it's not convenient to manage XML. But for me this way is easier at present. Again, because it's easier to manage all files in one place.

This XML-approach is extremely useful when you, say, renamed a directory with a lot of pages. In this case it's necessary to
create a single redirection rule for directory, instead of separate rule for each page inside it. For instance

```
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>blog/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>it-blog/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

According to this rule `example.com/blog/whatever` will be redirected to `example.com/it-blog/whatever`.

Another useful feature of such approach is that it replaces only prefixes. In the same way as with directories it's possible
to redirect page, but save query parameters. It could be suitable if there is some JS processing of these query
parameters. With x-amz-website-redirect-location metadata you'll probably loose them.

As I mentioned writing and reading XML might be inconvenient. To overcome this I wrote [a simple online tool](http://sukharevd.net/static/files/blog/s3routes/index.html)  in GWT to
convert plain text with former and new URLs to XML format. It uses the 
`KeyPrefixEquals` predicate and execute `ReplaceKeyPrefixWith` redirect.

Finally, according to [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff),
if website hosting is disabled, redirection support is not applicable for this bucket.

Comment: Does this feature support regular expressions ? : 

I want to add ".html" to all the files that do not end with a file extension.

For example: mysite.com/aaa/xxx should be redirected to -> mysite.com/aaa/xxx.html

I want to redirect every * to .html, but only if the file name doesn't end with a file extension.
(I don't want to do it to js files and not to folders ... )
Does this feature support regular expressions ? Can someone post examples with regular expressions ? (KeyPrefixEquals ^[^.]$ -> ReplaceKeyPrefixWith $1.html)

Comment: It does not support regular expressions so that would be impossible

Answer (score 7):

**Edit: See answer above as this functionality is now native in AWS**

Not really no.
There isn't an inbuilt feature which allows this, however, what you can do is to create your object and even if you don't save it as HTML, you can apply it as an HTML file.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.example.com/target/">
    <title>Redirect</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/target/">http://www.example.com/target/</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Look at this page here: View the source on it quickly.

view-source:http://carltonbale.com.s3.amazonaws.com/distance_chart.png

You can see an explanation here:

Point 8: http://carltonbale.com/9-hidden-features-of-amazon-s3

Comment: I forgot to mention that you would actually then create a header tag in the HTML which redirects.

Comment: I'd prefer if i could redirect in the header before the html is loaded. I know it's possible to change headers for Content-Type for example but can i also set a redirect header? Something like this:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 174

Comment: Hmm didn't know that multilines was disabled in comments. See edited question instead.

Answer (score 7):

The ability has been added recently: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/10/amazon-s3-support-for-website-redirects.html

Answer (score 4):

[AWSCLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) lets you do this easily now (sort of)

1. Make sure bucket is 100% public
2. Make sure bucket is in Website Hosting mode
3. Only refer to site using it's full URL `https://<bucket_name>.s3-website-<region>.amazonaws.com`
4. Use the `s3api` call to set the redirect:

```
aws s3api put-object --acl public-read --website-redirect-location "http://other-location.com" --bucket foo-bucket --key somewhere/blah
```

**Note**: You don't post any object to S3, because it will only serve a 301 and redirect `Location` header.

Test with

`curl -v 2 -L https://<bucket_name>.s3-website-<region>.amazonaws.com/somewhere/blah`

Comment: Getting 404. `Code: NoSuchKey Message: The specified key does not exist.`

Answer (score 3):

**htaccess 301 to Amazon S3 redirect translation**

---

htaccess style:

```
Redirect 301 /old/old.html http://www.new.com/new/new.html
```

translates to:

```
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>old/old.html</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <HostName>www.new.com</HostName>
        <Protocol>http</Protocol>
        <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>
        <ReplaceKeyWith>new/new.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

You could probably write a little script along the lines of:

```
// -----------------
// Javascript
// htaccess to amazon s3 redirect for static s3 websites.
// (XML goes into S3 Bucket Properties Editor > [x] Enable website hosting > Edit Redirection Rules box.)
// -----------------

var list = [
    "Redirect 301 /old/old-1.html http://www.new.com/new/new-1.html",
    "Redirect 301 /old/old-2.html http://www.new.com/new/new-2.html",
    "Redirect 301 /old/old-3.html http://www.new.com/new/new-3.html"
];

var output = [];

output.push('<?xml version="1.0"?>');
output.push('<RoutingRules>');

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){

    var item = list[i].replace("Redirect 301 /", "").split(" ");
    var oldLoc = item[0];
    var newLoc = item[1];

    output.push("   <RoutingRule>");
    output.push("       <Condition>");
    output.push("           <KeyPrefixEquals>" + oldLoc + "/KeyPrefixEquals>");
    output.push("       </Condition>");

    output.push("       <Redirect>");
    if(newLoc.substr(0, 1) == "/"){

        output.push("           <ReplaceKeyWith>" + newLoc + "</ReplaceKeyWith>");

    } else {

        var splitNewLoc = newLoc.replace("http://", "").split("/");
        var host = splitNewLoc.shift();
        var path = splitNewLoc.join("/");

        output.push("           <HostName>" + host + "</HostName>");
        output.push("           <Protocol>http</Protocol>");
        output.push("           <HttpRedirectCode>301</HttpRedirectCode>");

        if(path){
            output.push("           <ReplaceKeyWith>" + path + "</ReplaceKeyWith>");
        }

    }

    output.push("       </Redirect>");
    output.push("   </RoutingRule>");

}

output.push('</RoutingRules>');

print(output.join("\n"));
```

WARNING: Amazon limits the number of redirect rules to 50.