# How to serve server page inside cloudfront and s3 static files?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I serve my website using cloudfront s3 (static files). https://example.com

When I open particular url I want to get into the server, but stay on the same domain.

for example

- https://example.com/index.html -> serve from cloudfront and s3
- https://example.com/app.js -> serve from cloudfront and s3
- https://example.com/foo -> go direct to my server (https://api.example.com/api/foo) and foo will return html content and in the browser is will stay and display the `https://example.com/foo` url.

Is something can be possible to do with s3 and cloudfront? if so what the configure I need to be done to achieve this?

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272835/amazon-s3-object-redirect

Comment: no. I set `Website-Redirect-Location` and I redirect to https://api.example.com/api/foo instead of rewrite..

Comment: You can specify a different **origin server** for `/foo` to point to an Amazon EC2 instance, and other content with the origin as an Amazon S3 bucket. See: [Using Amazon S3 Origins, MediaPackage Channels, and Custom Origins for Web Distributions - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a `Cache behaviour` for URL path which should go to Dynamic website
And a `Default cache behaviour` (A catch everything else) which should go to `S3`.

When you create a new distribution, you specify settings for the `default cache behavior`, which automatically forwards all requests to the origin(for you its S3) that you specify when you create the distribution. After you create a distribution, you can create additional `cache behaviors` that define how CloudFront responds when it receives a request for objects that match a path pattern (in your case `/foo`)

If you are doing it through CloudFormation then see [AWS::CloudFront::Distribution CacheBehavior - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html).

From Console
[image]

And Then

[image: ![enter image description here]